# Puzzle swipe gesture

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5

Im trying to figure the best way available in iOS to solve the following:

Basically I've built a 4x6 tile matrix with UIButtons, each containing a letter. The buttons are contained within a UIView. (Apple, Fast, Tree)

```
A
P F
P A
L S
E T
T R E E
```

All UIButtons have userInteractionEnabled set to FALSE to receive touchesBegan calls. On creation, all UIButtons are placed into a NSMutableArray.

My challenge is how to Swipe&drag from a letter(starting point) and move to a destination letter, trying to "find" the complete word.Kind of like the Ruzzle App but only horizontal & Vertical swipes. 
The UIButtons that are being "multi-selected" have to change background color as a visual indication.

Im receiving the touch location via the touchesMoved. Does the entire code of detection has to be triggered under touchesMoved?

What will the best approach for this be? and the least process intensive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using touchesBegan/Moved methods, why don't you look into `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter`/`UIControlEventTouchDragInside` [events](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl)? That will give you better performance as the associated action will only be called when touch enters the button or is dragged inside the button. In these methods you can keep pushing the new buttons in an array as touch enters into their bounds and check for their position with respect to buttons pushed previously. In this approach I think you will have to handle the first button touch using `UIControlEventTouchDown` event.
I would love to know how you implement it finally.

Comment: Thank you zambrey, ill look into the method you mentioned and will let you know how it goes, thanks again!